# Motivation for Hirzebruch-Jung Modified Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, continued-fractions

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{N} \ \ s.t. \ \ a > b$ have $\gcd(a,b) =1$. We can define the Hirzebruch-Jung modified euclidean algorithm as follows:

Let $e_i \in \mathbb{N} >2$, and $ r_k \in \mathbb{N}$ where $0\le r_k<r_{k-1}$. Then we can do the following procedure (analogous to the standard Euclidean algorithm):
$$ \begin{array}{rcl} 
a &= & e_1b -r_1\\
b &= & e_2r_1 - r_2\\
r_1 &= &e_3r_2 -r_3\\
&...\\
r_{k-2} &= &e_ir_{k-1} = e_i
\end{array}$$
That last line is true because the $\gcd(a,b) =1$, by hypothesis.

Considering that the greatest common divisor is known by hypothesis, what is the utility of this modified Euclidean algorithm, and what was the motivation for its development? I have heard that it has applications to toric geometry, but I am not familiar with those.

Comment: Presumably, the procedure includes the specification, $0\le r_i<r_{i-1}$. The procedure bears the same relation to what might be called "negative-regular" continued fractions, as the usual Euclidean procedure bears to the usual continued fractions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I forgot to add that specification, but it is indeed required. I have edited the question accordingly. I presume by the "usual fractions" and such you mean what is described [here](http://www.albany.edu/~hammond/gellmu/examples/confrac.pdf) ?

Comment: Yes, though in this context only the finite continued fractions will arise.

Comment: In Perron's book these fractions called "reduced regular continued fractions. Probably they are older then Hirzebruch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the motivation for the Hirzebruch-Jung algorithm is not the algorithm itself, but the fact the it yields *directly* a very interesting continued fraction expansion. It is those, now called **Hirzebruch-Jung continued fractions**, that have a wide number of applications. A bit more on that later.

Using your notation (but changing $b$ with $r_o$ for clarity).

$$ \begin{array}{rcl} 
a &= & e_1r_0 -r_1\\
r_0 &= & e_2r_1 - r_2\\
r_1 &= &e_3r_2 -r_3\\
&...\\
r_{k-2} &= &e_ir_{k-1} = e_i
\end{array}$$

By simple division you get:

$$ \begin{array}{rcl} 
a/r_0 &= & e_1 -r_1/r_0\\
r_0/r_1 &= & e_2 - r_2/r_1\\
r_1/r_2 &= &e_3 -r_3/r_2\\
&...\\
r_{k-2}/r_{k-2} &= &e_i
\end{array}$$

And from that you can simply read off:

$$a/r_0 = e_1 -\frac{1}{e_1-\frac{1}{...-\frac{1}{e_i}}}$$

It is those finite continued fractions $a/r_0$ that have, among many others, applications to toric varieties. To quote from D. I. Dais' "[Geometric Combinatorics in the Study of Compact Toric Surfaces](http://www.math.uoc.gr:1080/Members/ddais/Dais_Anogia.pdf)" (2000):

> "Examining two-dimensional toric singularities "under the microscope"
>   one discovers a peculiar algebro-geometric world endowed with a rich
>   combinatorial structure. Viewed historically, everything begins with
>   Hirzebruch-Jung continued fractions."

For some more motivation and applications, I quote form a very recent (2015) [paper](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwjkoLfzrcbIAhUJVhoKHYVtAi8&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.scirp.org%2FJournal%2FPaperDownload.aspx%3FpaperID%3D59458&usg=AFQjCNGKzcZ-DFePRQjWKD7f_lFHlSdttg&sig2=K9IC1p_we5RXn9RnNPzKhg):

> "Hirzebruch-Jung (H-J) continued fractions are widely used in various
>   branches of mathematics as well as in theoretical physics. First of
>   all, HJ-continued fractions arise naturally in the minimal resolution
>   of cyclic quotient (that is, Hirzebruch-Jung) surface singularities of
>   the type $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}_p$, which is also known as
>   HJ-resolution" [...]
>
> HJ-continued fractions are used also to describe the plumbing
>   decomposition of the other type of link of surface singularities,
>   namely, Seifert fibered homology spheres (Sfh-spheres), particularly
>   Brieskorn homology spheres (Bh-spheres) [...]
>
> In condensed matter theory, the HJ-continued fractions are used to
>   describe fractional quantum Hall (FQH) systems with k levels of
>   hierarchy [...]
>
> Also, in topological string theory, the structure of internal space
>   (Calabi-Yau threefold) can be encoded in terms of HJ-continued
>   fraction expansion of positive integers, which are the topological
>   invariants of the internal space and define the mode of interactions
>   between D-branes"

Answer (score 3):

This algorithm gives best possible left (or right, it depends on the first step) convergents to a given number, while usual continued fractions give left and right convergents.

From gemetrical point of view convergents to ususal continued fractions for $a/N$ correspond to the verteces of two sails (in 1st **and** 2nd quarter) for the lattice generated by vectors $(a,1)$  and $(N,0)$ while "negative-regular" continued fractions (aka reduced regular continued fractions) give the verteces of only one sail (in 1st **or** 2nd quarter), see [Geometric proof of Rödseth's formula for Frobenius numbers](http://iam.khv.ru/articles/Ustinov/nth32_eng.pdf) for the picture.

Another application is [Conway tangles](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0311499.pdf). The shortest way to generate a tangle $T$ with given invariant $i(T)$ is to expand $i(T)$ into a "negative-regular" continued fraction.